# Help with chinese letters

Tags: characters

Hi I own a printing company and a client submitted the following documents so that I recreate for him following stamps

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE0sD.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxbCJ.jpg

I have no idea what these stamps are and what is written there, my questions

1) Is it legally ok for the stamps to be recreated?

2) If yes, could someone be so nice and type for me the letters which are within the red circles.

Thank you

Comment: It is illegal to make fake official government stamps.  Can you recreate the stamps with graphic an all? I am curious.

Comment: Sure you can recreate a stamp; all you need is an image from which a stamp can be etched. You say making such a stamp is illegal; can you detail what law in what jurisdiction prohibits that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's stamps of p.r.c. governmental office.

**don't do it**

counterfeiting government stamp is an serious offence; in most of places in this world, it's criminal activities.

again, **don't do it**

edited.

@john frazer, CL is not an "underground / dark" site. imo, your comments are inappropriate. encouraging others to "recreate a stamp", may i ask, what's the moral?

about "what law in what jurisdiction prohibits that", here're:

provided by @frenzy li. in mainland china, the 中華人民共和國刑法　第二百八十條

> **偽造**、變造、買賣或者盜竊、搶奪、毀滅**國家機關的**公文、證件、**印章**的，處三年以下有期徒刑、拘役、管制或者剝奪政治權利，並處罰金；情節嚴重的，處三年以上十年以下有期徒刑，並處罰金。

[https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/中华人民共和国刑法](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E4%B8%AD%E5%8D%8E%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9B%BD%E5%88%91%E6%B3%95)

in colonial era, there's a "forgery ordinance" in hong kong, which mentioned:

> forge or counterfeit the stamp or impression of ariy of the seals

http://oelawhk.lib.hku.hk/items/show/206

i hope that, this should provide enough info for you, to stop the thinking of "make a stamp that looks like an official stamp".

again, such act is an offence, **don't do it**.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that they may be official, but I was not sure.

Comment: This quickly escalated from Chinese SE to Legal SE. Funny.

Comment: I don't think it's illegal to make a stamp that looks like an official stamp as long as you don't use it within that country. Also, I've never heard about any law prohibiting to copy a stamp, although there are laws to prohibit printing counterfeit currency. It's certainly illegal to assume authority where none has been granted. Speaking of which, if my signature happens to look exactly like the Prime Minister's signature, I can only be sued when I use that fact to posture as the PM; I can still use that signature for all my legal dealings.

Comment: Citation: 《中华人民共和国刑法》 Criminal Law of the P.R.C. code 280. Up to 7 years' of imprisonment.